# Split lines then search

Tags: python, list, split

I am currently reading in a serial port continually and looking for a certain keyword that exists.

```
while certain_condition_isTrue:
    menu = ser_port.read(ser_port.inWaiting())
    menu = menu.lower()
    menulines = menu.splitlines()
```

After the loop ends,

```
for line in menulines:
    if stringToFind in line:
        print "string is found!"
```

This solution doesn't work well for me because I need to check constantly if the keyword is found, not just loop through the list at the very end. Is there any way to accomplish this?

I tried something like:

```
while certain_condition_isTrue:
    menu = ser_port.read(ser_port.inWaiting())
    menu = menu.lower()
    menulines = menu.splitlines()

    if stringToFind in menulines
        print "found"
        break
```

Comment: Soooo, that's it: your second code is correct, you're just missing a `:` at the end of the `if` statement.

Comment: Instead of `break`, you can do `certain_condition_isTrue = False`.

Comment: What is wrong with your last code sample that you provided?

Comment: The second code sample would never "find" the keyword. I changed menulines to menu and that seems to be working now.